# What does the single asterisk inside parentheses "(*)" do in C++?

Tags: c++

I found code that looks like this:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Example*(*)()> map_type;
```

and after searching for a while, I still can't figure out what the (*) operator does exactly.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You’ll like this: [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org). If you manage to break down the expression to valid C, it’ll tell you what it’s about.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that link, looks useful!

Comment: @JonasWielicki: Except it's C++ :)

Comment: Oh, yeah, it's for C I guess, but still bookmarked!  Anyone know of anything like that for C++?

Comment: @staticx: Example is the name of a class.

Comment: @autobahn http://cdecl.org is often fine for C++ too. It's fine here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I just tried it with his code.. doesn't work. http://cdecl.org/?q=typedef%20std::map%3Cstd::string,%20Example*%28*%29%28%29%3E%20map_type; (don't click, have to copy this link and try it)

Comment: @autobahn: Could have been a typedef.. who knows.

Comment: You know what `std::map` is. What you need to know is what `Example*(*)()` is. So try it like this: `void foo(int*(*)())`. Here I substitute `int` for `Example` since http://cdecl.org does not know what `Example` is. Here's the [link](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+foo%28int*%28*%29%28%29%29)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sure, but that's C. My point is that it doesn't know what a `map` or the C++ syntax.

Comment: @staticx I think asker, and you, know what `std::map` is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Of course I do. But you can't just paste it in there and always expect it to work. Caveat emptor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parens here are use to impose precedence. The type

```
Example*(*)()
```

is a pointer to function returning pointer to `Example`.

Without the parens you would have

```
Example**()
```

which would be a function returning pointer to pointer to `Example`.

Answer (score 5):

This is the syntax used to declare a pointer to a function (your case) or an array. Take the declaration

```
typedef Example* (*myFunctionType)();
```

this will make the line

```
typedef std::map<std::string, myFunctionType> map_type;
```

be exactly equivalent to the line you've given. Note that the difference between `Example* (*myFunctionType)()` and `Example* (*)()` is only that the name of the type has been omitted.

Answer (score 0):

It's a **function pointer** declaration.

This *typedef* means the std::map is mapping strings to function pointers, that receives **void** and returns **Example***.

You could use it like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

typedef  int Example;

Example* myExampleFunc() {
    return new Example[10];
};

typedef std::map<std::string, Example*(*)()> map_type;

int main() {

    map_type myMap;
    // initializing
    myMap["key"] = myExampleFunc;

    // calling myExampleFunc

    Example *example = myMap["key"]();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make complicated pointer types a lot less confusing in C++11 thanks to template typedefs:

```
template<typename T> using ptr = T*;

typedef std::map<std::string, ptr<Example*()>> map_type;
```